# Fail to deploy sample chaincode on Fabric from fabric-samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to deploy a sample ChainCode on Fabric test-network. I bring up the network and then I create a channel and then I run this command: `./network.sh deployCC` and I get the following error:

```
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image inspection failed: Get "http://unix.sock/images/dev-peer0.org1.example.com-basic_1.0-4ec191e793b27e953ff2ede5a8bcc63152cecb1e4c3f301a26e22692c61967ad-42f57faac8360472e47cbbbf3940e81bba83439702d085878d148089a1b213ca/json": dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are running Docker on a Mac ? Docker made a change in version 2.4.0.0 (I think) and it causes a problem. You need to uncheck the option "use gRPC fuse".
see https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/77402508?p=Created,,,20,2,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,77402508
for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I did that, since it is also stated as an issue in the common issues at the HL Fabric readthedocs website, but it did not work.

Comment: If you still can't make it work then I would recommend just running a linux VM instead as it avoids some of these platform issues. Docker for Mac still has to run a Linux VM anyway to run linux containers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Docker Desktop on macOS, this problem is caused by a newer version of Docker Desktop for macOS. To resolve this issue, in the Docker Desktop preferences, uncheck the box Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing to use the legacy osxfs file sharing instead and click Apply & Restart.

If you see errors on your create, approve, commit, invoke or query commands, make sure you have properly updated the channel name and chaincode name.