# Hyperledger Fabric 2.x Error: chaincode install failed with status

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am struggling with Hyperledger Fabric for quite some time now. And the problem is I am struggling at the initial stage. I am new to Blockchain, and I am supposed to work on Hyperledger fabric in my existing project.

Theoretically, I have understood things properly, but I am facing issues practically.

I am trying to follow Hyperledger Fabric 2.x doc and downloaded all the binaries and requirements as listed.

I created a channel and started by network using this command (fabric-samples - test-network):

```
./network.sh up createChannel
```

The above command runs fine.

next, I am running this command:

```
./network.sh deployCC -ccl javascript
```

And when I run this, I am getting the following error:

```
deploying chaincode on channel 'mychannel'
executing with the following
- CHANNEL_NAME: mychannel
- CC_NAME: basic
- CC_SRC_PATH: NA
- CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: javascript
- CC_VERSION: 1.0
- CC_SEQUENCE: 1
- CC_END_POLICY: NA
- CC_COLL_CONFIG: NA
- CC_INIT_FCN: NA
- DELAY: 3
- MAX_RETRY: 5
- VERBOSE: false
Determining the path to the chaincode
asset-transfer-basic
+ peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-      javascript/ --lang node --label basic_1.0
+ res=0
Chaincode is packaged
Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=1
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image inspection failed: Get "http://unix.sock/images/dev-peer0.org1.example.com-basic_1.0-b359a077730d7f44d6a437ad49d1da951f6a01c6d1eed4f85b8b1f5a08617fe7-40e7bb7f8ee7f34afff742475a34eddac41427d0a83a545b2bb44d6ea8b53676/json": dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed.
Deploying chaincode failed
```

Please let me know what exactly am I doing wrong as I feel I am following things as per the doc, and if there is any article that is written for beginners for hyperledger fabric 2.x, please refer.

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275235/fail-to-deploy-sample-chaincode-on-fabric-from-fabric-samples
if you still have problems try running natively on linux

Comment: Thank you @david_k for helping me with this. I did disable gRPC fuse in docker settings but when I do that this command ./network.sh up createChannel stops working too. I will update my question with the error.

Comment: @david_k Thank you. Something strange happened. It just worked. I did this multiple times today but not sure how it worked now. Anyways, Thank you. I'll need to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who is facing this issue. As David suggested in the comment we need to turn off nGrpc.

[image]

And make sure before turning it off, pull your network down using this command

```
./network.sh down
```